# JavaScript Library to show tooltips with keyboard shortcuts when holding down alt/ctrl

Tags: javascript, accessibility

Is there a JavaScript library that, when the user holds down ctrl/alt, will display tooltips over elements on the page that have associated keyboard shortcuts (via an `accesskey` attribute) that use that key?
ctrl

Comment: A browser extension perhaps? Rather than a "JavaScript library"...? Or is this something you wish to apply to your own website? When you refer to "associated keyboard shortcuts", are you referring to AccessKeys, or something more?

Comment: It's a web app, and it probably would have to work with AccessKeys

Comment: @w3d Thanks for the AccessKeys hint. I was able to find something that does what I'm after.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this for your site or do it within your browser? I know Opera does this automatically.

Comment: @RyanB this is a for a B2B web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [KeyTips](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/KeyTips-jQuery-Plugin) is the one I'd seen before. It's certainly looks better than KeyCandy, although I like how KeyCandy makes Ctrl the modifier for accesskeys.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

There are [some issues with browser reserved shortcuts](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=33056) but as this is an internal intranet site if I make it a [hosted app](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide) for chrome [it would be able to handle any shortcut](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84332)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for: [KeyCandy](http://aaronmccall.github.com/KeyCandy/). Although I'll have to fix the flicker when Ctrl is held down.

I knew I'd seen something like this before. Not sure if it's the same one. Anyone got a better one?

Comment: FWIW 2 issues: 1- The [keyCandy Demo](http://aaronmccall.github.com/KeyCandy/test.html) does not seem to work in IE8. 2- be very careful relying on accessKeys, browser hotkeys overrule AccessKeys, and if the user is using assistive technology, then those have precident. The [UK Gov standard](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/hl1/help/dg_020463) is the closest thing to a standard set of AccessKeys.

Answer (score -1):

You don't require any library for keyboard shortcuts. Simply use the keys in the Object passed in the keydown object. For instance:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#element");
element.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    //Ctrl+Alt+Del
    if (event.key === "Delete" && event.ctrlKey === true && event.altKey === true) {
        //Disables Ctrl+Alt+Del
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("You pressed Ctrl+Alt+Del, too bad!");
    }
    //Win+R (On Windows, it opens up the Run Prompt)
    else if (event.key === "r" && event.metaKey === true) {
        //Disable it once again
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("You can never 'run' from me!!");
    }
    //Create A Save Prompt When Users Ctrl+S
    else if (event.key === "s" && event.ctrlKey === true) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Give The User Options
        alert("First choose an option to save, then continue.");
    }
});
```

And then, from there, simply add the `title` attribute to the element, to create a browser generated tooltip, and simply `focus()` on the element when the shortcut is pressed.

JavaScript:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#element");

if (event.key === "h" && event.ctrlKey === true) {
    event.preventDefault();
    element.focus();
}
```

HTML:

```
<p title="help section" id="element">Help Help Help<p>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This down't answer the question. The question was how do you show a **tooltip** beside all elements that have a shortcut (via an `accesskey` attribute) when the `ctrl`/`alt` key is held down.

Comment: @SamHasler I changed my answer, please revise it once more.

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't answer the question. I wanted something that would show **all** possible shortcuts when `Ctrl` was held down. I'm happy with KeyTips (see the image I've added to the answer).